# Alamofire: What is wrong with this syntax? "Extra argument in call"

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming, alamofire

I am using Alamofire in Swift for networking.

I need to post data as httpbody to an url.

Here is my code:

```
let parameters = ["username": "Admin", "password": "somepassword", "client_id": "Example", "grant_type": "password", "refresh_token": "string"];

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX", parameters:  parameters, encoding: .JSON(options: nil)).responseJSON { response in
        print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
        print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

        if let json = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
        }
        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
        }
    }
```

This does not compile, instead i get "extra argument in call"

What is wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what version of the alamofire are you using?

Comment: I use version 4.2.0

Comment: From my understanding the "parameters" will be the httpbody?

Comment: change encoding to **encoding: JSONEncoding.default**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Alamofire of version 4+, there is a different syntax to create a request (see [migration guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#making-requests)):

```
Alamofire.request("https://XXXXXXXXXXXX", 
                  method: .post,
                  parameters: parameters,
                  encoding: JSONEncoding.default) .responseJSON { response in
    // TODO: rest
}
```